# Drupal 8, how to disable a view during a installation profile's hook_install?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-8

I have a custom installation profile, that has a dependency on views and other custom modules. One such module is an admin content module that has a custom view meant to replace the "content" view (/admin/content).

In general, I'm able to disable the content view programatically (this is on a drush file that I call with drush scr).

```
$view = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('view')->load('content');
if (!is_null($view)) {
  $view->setStatus(FALSE);
  $view->save();
}
```

However, this works if the site was installed before. If I try to run this in the install hook of my custom profile the view object is null.

```
function my_profile_install() {
  // Previous code here
}
```

The view is null and I cannot disable it. I'm still not too proficient on Drupal 8 inner workings, I'm going trough code and trying to identify what could be the reason but no luck so far.

I've made sure that both the node module (this is where the standard content view is defined) and the views module are loaded before requesting for the view. It still returns empty.

```
Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('node');
Drupal::moduleHandler()->load('views');
```

I also did this:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()
  ->getEditable('views.view.content')
  ->set('status', TRUE)
  ->save();
```

This "works". The problem is that this breaks the views listing page with an exception. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

So, after thinking of alternatives I've come up with this logic.

Implementing hook_install_tasks and create a task that disables the view.

```
function my_profile_install_tasks() {
  return [
    'my_profile_disable_views' => [
      'display_name' => 'Disabling unused views',
      'display' => TRUE,
      'type' => 'normal',
      'run' => INSTALL_TASK_RUN_IF_NOT_COMPLETED,
    ],
  ];
}

function my_profile_disable_views() {
  $view = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->getStorage('view')->load('content');
  if (!is_null($view)) {
    $view->setStatus(FALSE);
    $view->save();
  }
}
```

This works without problem installing from Drush or from UI.